# Installing Java on Debian

Tags: linux, installation, debian, java, jre

I need to get Java working for an online class, but I'm not having any luck. I've installed the package sun-java6-jre successfully, but Java still does not load in browser.

The Oracle instructions here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/manual-plugin-install-linux-136395.html say I should have a file called "libnpjp2.so" -- I don't see any file named that (or anything similar) in the package file listing here: http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/all/sun-java6-jre/filelist

There are no files at all that end in *.so -- where did I go wrong with this install? Did I install the wrong java6 package?

```
# java -version
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are tricky licensing issues going on with Java (triply so after Oracle bought Sun). The `sun-java*` packages are not the "official" Java installation in Debian and other free operating systems — the open implementation [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) is, available in the `openjdk-*` packages.

The browser plugin functionality that goes with this Java version is called [IcedTea](http://icedtea.classpath.org/wiki/Main_Page), available as `icedtea*-plugin`.

So, if you want to go "the Oracle way", then you should download `.deb` packages directly from Oracle (given they provide them) and follow their instructions. If you want to go "the Debian way", install e.g. `icedtea-7-plugin`, which should pull in the needed OpenJDK packages.

Other references:

- http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-java-faq/ch-browser-java.html
- http://wiki.debian.org/Java